# Render happens before the request using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I need to make a request before rendering. The request data will be stored in a redux state. Because it is my App.js it contains the necessary routes for the application. However, the rendering of the routes takes place before the request made in useEffect.
Can anybody help me? I need the request data saved in the redux state before rendering routes or anything else.

**App.js**

```
const App = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const setData = (data) => dispatch(actions.setData(data))

  const fetchData = async () => {
    await axios.get('https://link-api.com/')
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data)
        setData(response.data)
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
      <Router>

        <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/page4/:id" component={Page4} />
            <Route path="/page3" component={Page3} />
            <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
            <Route path="/" component={Home} />
          </Switch>

      </Router>
  );
}

export default App
```

**Home.js**

```
const Home= () => {

    const data = useSelector(state => state.myReducers.data)

    useEffect(() => {
            console.log("data")
         }
      }, []);

    return (
        <>
          //view_home
        </>
    )
}

export default Home
```

Example: in this case, the log inserted in the useEffect of *Home.js* appears even before the one inserted in *App.js*

Comment: As per React documentation (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) "useEffect" hook aim is to handle side effects *after* the component render. If you want to stick to functional component, you need to rely on conditional render, as per @ysvet answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases when you have to fetch something before rendering - consider conditional rendering.
For example add a new state which keeps loading status. Set it initially to true, and when the data is fetched - set it to false.
And when it's false - render whatever you need.